# How to install package with module options in vcpkg manifest use?

Tags: vcpkg

I'm trying to build `PCL` library with `visualization` module on my Visual Studio 2019 project.
This is my `vcpkg.json` file for my project.

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": [
    {
      "name": "opencv4"
    },
    {
      "name": "vtk"
    },
    {
      "name": "pcl"
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I build my project, the list of vcpkg is following:

```
PS C:\vcpkg> .\vcpkg.exe list --x-install-root=C:\MyProject\vcpkg_installed

boost-algorithm:x64-windows                       1.82.0#2            Boost algorithm module
boost-align:x64-windows                           1.82.0#2            Boost align module
boost-any:x64-windows                             1.82.0#2            Boost any module
boost-array:x64-windows                           1.82.0#2            Boost array module
boost-asio:x64-windows                            1.82.0#3            Boost asio module
boost-assert:x64-windows                          1.82.0#2            Boost assert module
boost-atomic:x64-windows                          1.82.0#3            Boost atomic module
boost-bimap:x64-windows                           1.82.0#2            Boost bimap module
boost-bind:x64-windows                            1.82.0#2            Boost bind module
boost-build:x64-windows                           1.82.0#2            Boost.Build
boost-chrono:x64-windows                          1.82.0#2            Boost chrono module
boost-circular-buffer:x64-windows                 1.82.0#2            Boost circular_buffer module
boost-concept-check:x64-windows                   1.82.0#2            Boost concept_check module
boost-config:x64-windows                          1.82.0#2            Boost config module
boost-container-hash:x64-windows                  1.82.0#2            Boost container_hash module
boost-container:x64-windows                       1.82.0#2            Boost container module
boost-context:x64-windows                         1.82.0#2            Boost context module
boost-conversion:x64-windows                      1.82.0#2            Boost conversion module
boost-core:x64-windows                            1.82.0#2            Boost core module
boost-coroutine:x64-windows                       1.82.0#2            Boost coroutine module
boost-date-time:x64-windows                       1.82.0#2            Boost date_time module
boost-describe:x64-windows                        1.82.0#2            Boost describe module
boost-detail:x64-windows                          1.82.0#2            Boost detail module
boost-dynamic-bitset:x64-windows                  1.82.0#2            Boost dynamic_bitset module
boost-endian:x64-windows                          1.82.0#2            Boost endian module
boost-exception:x64-windows                       1.82.0#2            Boost exception module
boost-filesystem:x64-windows                      1.82.0#2            Boost filesystem module
boost-foreach:x64-windows                         1.82.0#2            Boost foreach module
boost-format:x64-windows                          1.82.0#2            Boost format module
boost-function-types:x64-windows                  1.82.0#2            Boost function_types module
boost-function:x64-windows                        1.82.0#2            Boost function module
boost-functional:x64-windows                      1.82.0#2            Boost functional module
boost-fusion:x64-windows                          1.82.0#2            Boost fusion module
boost-graph:x64-windows                           1.82.0#2            Boost graph module
boost-integer:x64-windows                         1.82.0#2            Boost integer module
boost-interprocess:x64-windows                    1.82.0#2            Boost interprocess module
boost-intrusive:x64-windows                       1.82.0#2            Boost intrusive module
boost-io:x64-windows                              1.82.0#2            Boost io module
boost-iostreams:x64-windows                       1.82.0#2            Boost iostreams module
boost-iostreams[bzip2]:x64-windows                                    Support bzip2 filters
boost-iostreams[lzma]:x64-windows                                     Support LZMA/xz filters
boost-iostreams[zlib]:x64-windows                                     Support zlib filters
boost-iostreams[zstd]:x64-windows                                     Support zstd filters
boost-iterator:x64-windows                        1.82.0#2            Boost iterator module
boost-lambda:x64-windows                          1.82.0#2            Boost lambda module
boost-lexical-cast:x64-windows                    1.82.0#2            Boost lexical_cast module
boost-math:x64-windows                            1.82.0#2            Boost math module
boost-modular-build-helper:x64-windows            1.82.0#4            Internal vcpkg port used to build Boost libraries
boost-move:x64-windows                            1.82.0#2            Boost move module
boost-mp11:x64-windows                            1.82.0#2            Boost mp11 module
boost-mpl:x64-windows                             1.82.0#2            Boost mpl module
boost-multi-array:x64-windows                     1.82.0#2            Boost multi_array module
boost-multi-index:x64-windows                     1.82.0#2            Boost multi_index module
boost-numeric-conversion:x64-windows              1.82.0#2            Boost numeric_conversion module
boost-optional:x64-windows                        1.82.0#2            Boost optional module
boost-parameter:x64-windows                       1.82.0#2            Boost parameter module
boost-phoenix:x64-windows                         1.82.0#2            Boost phoenix module
boost-pool:x64-windows                            1.82.0#2            Boost pool module
boost-predef:x64-windows                          1.82.0#2            Boost predef module
boost-preprocessor:x64-windows                    1.82.0#2            Boost preprocessor module
boost-property-map:x64-windows                    1.82.0#2            Boost property_map module
boost-property-tree:x64-windows                   1.82.0#2            Boost property_tree module
boost-proto:x64-windows                           1.82.0#2            Boost proto module
boost-ptr-container:x64-windows                   1.82.0#2            Boost ptr_container module
boost-random:x64-windows                          1.82.0#2            Boost random module
boost-range:x64-windows                           1.82.0#2            Boost range module
boost-ratio:x64-windows                           1.82.0#2            Boost ratio module
boost-rational:x64-windows                        1.82.0#2            Boost rational module
boost-regex:x64-windows                           1.82.0#2            Boost regex module
boost-serialization:x64-windows                   1.82.0#2            Boost serialization module
boost-signals2:x64-windows                        1.82.0#2            Boost signals2 module
boost-smart-ptr:x64-windows                       1.82.0#2            Boost smart_ptr module
boost-sort:x64-windows                            1.82.0#2            Boost sort module
boost-spirit:x64-windows                          1.82.0#2            Boost spirit module
boost-static-assert:x64-windows                   1.82.0#2            Boost static_assert module
boost-system:x64-windows                          1.82.0#2            Boost system module
boost-thread:x64-windows                          1.82.0#2            Boost thread module
boost-throw-exception:x64-windows                 1.82.0#2            Boost throw_exception module
boost-tokenizer:x64-windows                       1.82.0#2            Boost tokenizer module
boost-tti:x64-windows                             1.82.0#2            Boost tti module
boost-tuple:x64-windows                           1.82.0#2            Boost tuple module
boost-type-index:x64-windows                      1.82.0#2            Boost type_index module
boost-type-traits:x64-windows                     1.82.0#2            Boost type_traits module
boost-typeof:x64-windows                          1.82.0#2            Boost typeof module
boost-uninstall:x64-windows                       1.82.0#2            Internal vcpkg port used to uninstall Boost
boost-unordered:x64-windows                       1.82.0#2            Boost unordered module
boost-utility:x64-windows                         1.82.0#2            Boost utility module
boost-uuid:x64-windows                            1.82.0#2            Boost uuid module
boost-variant2:x64-windows                        1.82.0#2            Boost variant2 module
boost-variant:x64-windows                         1.82.0#2            Boost variant module
boost-vcpkg-helpers:x64-windows                   1.82.0#2            Internal vcpkg port used to modularize Boost
boost-winapi:x64-windows                          1.82.0#2            Boost winapi module
boost-xpressive:x64-windows                       1.82.0#2            Boost xpressive module
brotli:x64-windows                                1.0.9#5             a generic-purpose lossless compression algorithm...
bzip2:x64-windows                                 1.0.8#4             bzip2 is a freely available, patent free, high-q...
bzip2[tool]:x64-windows                                               Builds bzip2 executable
cereal:x64-windows                                1.3.2#1             a header-only C++11 serialization library (built...
cgns:x64-windows                                  4.3.0#4             The CFD General Notation System (CGNS) provides ...
cgns[hdf5]:x64-windows                                                Enable hdf5 support
cgns[lfs]:x64-windows                                                 Enable LFS support
cgns[lfsselector]:x64-windows                                         Selector for LFS
curl:x64-windows                                  8.2.0               A library for transferring data with URLs
curl[non-http]:x64-windows                                            Enables protocols beyond HTTP/HTTPS/HTTP2
curl[schannel]:x64-windows                                            SSL support (Secure Channel)
curl[ssl]:x64-windows                                                 Default SSL backend
curl[sspi]:x64-windows                                                SSPI support
double-conversion:x64-windows                     3.2.1#1             Efficient binary-decimal and decimal-binary conv...
egl-registry:x64-windows                          2022-09-20          the EGL API and Extension Registry
eigen3:x64-windows                                3.4.0#2             C++ template library for linear algebra: matrice...
expat:x64-windows                                 2.5.0#3             XML parser library written in C
exprtk:x64-windows                                2022-01-01#2        Simple to use, easy to integrate and extremely e...
flann:x64-windows                                 2019-04-07#7        Fast Library for Approximate Nearest Neighbors
fmt:x64-windows                                   10.0.0              Formatting library for C++. It can be used as a ...
freetype:x64-windows                              2.12.1#3            A library to render fonts.
freetype[brotli]:x64-windows                                          Support decompression of WOFF2 streams
freetype[bzip2]:x64-windows                                           Support bzip2 compressed fonts.
freetype[png]:x64-windows                                             Support PNG compressed OpenType embedded bitmaps.
freetype[zlib]:x64-windows                                            Use zlib instead of internal library for DEFLATE
gklib:x64-windows                                 2022-07-27#2        General helper libraries for KarypisLab.
glew:x64-windows                                  2.2.0#3             The OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library (GLEW) is ...
hdf5:x64-windows                                  1.14.0#1            HDF5 is a data model, library, and file format f...
hdf5[szip]:x64-windows                                                Build with szip
hdf5[tools]:x64-windows                                               Build hdf tools
hdf5[zlib]:x64-windows                                                Build with zlib
jsoncpp:x64-windows                               1.9.5               jsoncpp is an implementation of a JSON reader an...
libharu:x64-windows                               2.4.3               libharu - free PDF library
libiconv:x64-windows                              1.17#1              GNU Unicode text conversion
libjpeg-turbo:x64-windows                         2.1.5.1#2           libjpeg-turbo is a JPEG image codec that uses SI...
liblzma:x64-windows                               5.4.3#1             Compression library with an API similar to that ...
libogg:x64-windows                                1.3.5#1             Ogg is a multimedia container format, and the na...
libpng:x64-windows                                1.6.39#1            libpng is a library implementing an interface fo...
libtheora:x64-windows                             1.2.0alpha1-2...    Theora is a free and open video compression form...
libwebp:x64-windows                               1.3.0#1             WebP codec: library to encode and decode images ...
libwebp[libwebpmux]:x64-windows                                       Build the libwebpmux library
libwebp[nearlossless]:x64-windows                                     Enable near-lossless encoding
libwebp[simd]:x64-windows                                             Enable any SIMD optimization.
libwebp[unicode]:x64-windows                                          Build Unicode executables. (Adds definition UNIC...
libxml2:x64-windows                               2.10.3#1            Libxml2 is the XML C parser and toolkit develope...
libxml2[iconv]:x64-windows                                            Add ICONV support
libxml2[lzma]:x64-windows                                             Use LZMA
libxml2[zlib]:x64-windows                                             Use ZLib
lz4:x64-windows                                   1.9.4#1             Lossless compression algorithm, providing compre...
matio:x64-windows                                 1.5.23#2            MATLAB MAT File I/O Library
matio[hdf5]:x64-windows                                               Check for HDF5 library
matio[zlib]:x64-windows                                               Check for zlib library
metis:x64-windows                                 2022-07-27          Serial Graph Partitioning and Fill-reducing Matr...
netcdf-c:x64-windows                              4.8.1#3             A set of self-describing, machine-independent da...
netcdf-c[dap]:x64-windows                                             Build with DAP remote access client support
netcdf-c[hdf5]:x64-windows                                            Build with HDF5 support
netcdf-c[nczarr]:x64-windows                                          Build with NCZarr cloud storage access support
netcdf-c[netcdf-4]:x64-windows                                        Build with netCDF-4 support
netcdf-c[platform-default-features]:x64-windows                       Enable platform-dependent default features
nlohmann-json:x64-windows                         3.11.2              JSON for Modern C++
opencv4:x64-windows                               4.7.0#6             computer vision library
opencv4[default-features]:x64-windows                                 Platform-dependent default features
opencv4[dnn]:x64-windows                                              Enable dnn module
opencv4[jpeg]:x64-windows                                             JPEG support for opencv
opencv4[png]:x64-windows                                              PNG support for opencv
opencv4[quirc]:x64-windows                                            Enable QR code module
opencv4[tiff]:x64-windows                                             TIFF support for opencv
opencv4[webp]:x64-windows                                             WebP support for opencv
opengl-registry:x64-windows                       2022-09-29#1        the API and Extension registries for the OpenGL ...
opengl:x64-windows                                2022-12-04#3        Open Graphics Library (OpenGL)[3][4][5] is a cro...
pcl:x64-windows                                   1.13.1              Point Cloud Library (PCL) is open source library...
pegtl:x64-windows                                 3.2.7               The Parsing Expression Grammar Template Library ...
pkgconf:x64-windows                               1.8.0#5             pkgconf is a program which helps to configure co...
proj:x64-windows                                  9.2.1               PROJ library for cartographic projections
proj[net]:x64-windows                                                 Enable network support
proj[tiff]:x64-windows                                                Enable TIFF support to read some grids
protobuf:x64-windows                              3.21.12             Protocol Buffers - Google's data interchange format
pugixml:x64-windows                               1.13.0              Light-weight, simple and fast XML parser for C++...
qhull:x64-windows                                 8.0.2#4             computes the convex hull, Delaunay triangulation...
quirc:x64-windows                                 1.1#3               quirc is one of the C library available for scan...
seacas:x64-windows                                2022-11-22#5        The Sandia Engineering Analysis Code Access Syst...
sqlite3:x64-windows                               3.42.0#1            SQLite is a software library that implements a s...
sqlite3[json1]:x64-windows                                            Enable JSON functionality for sqlite3
sqlite3[tool]:x64-windows                                             Build sqlite3 executable
szip:x64-windows                                  2.1.1#11            Szip compression software, providing lossless co...
tiff:x64-windows                                  4.5.1#2             A library that supports the manipulation of TIFF...
tiff[jpeg]:x64-windows                                                Support JPEG compression in TIFF image files
tiff[lzma]:x64-windows                                                Support LZMA compression in TIFF image files
tiff[zip]:x64-windows                                                 Support ZIP/deflate compression in TIFF image files
utfcpp:x64-windows                                3.2.3               UTF-8 with C++ in a Portable Way
vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-windows                    2022-02-06#1
vcpkg-cmake-get-vars:x64-windows                  2023-03-02
vcpkg-cmake:x64-windows                           2023-05-04
vcpkg-get-python-packages:x64-windows             2022-06-30
vcpkg-pkgconfig-get-modules:x64-windows           2023-02-25
vcpkg-tool-meson:x64-windows                      0.63                Meson build system
verdict:x64-windows                               1.4.0               Compute quality functions of 2 and 3-dimensional...
vtk:x64-windows                                   9.2.0-pv5.11.0#8    Software system for 3D computer graphics, image ...
zlib:x64-windows                                  1.2.13              A compression library
zstd:x64-windows                                  1.5.5               Zstandard - Fast real-time compression algorithm
```

As you can see, the `opencv4` package is installed with its module(`opencv4[dnn]`, `opencv4[jpeg]`, etc.). However, the only core library(`pcl:x64-windows`) is installed for `pcl` package. There are lots of module of `pcl` in vcpkg.

```
PS C:\vcpkg> .\vcpkg.exe search pcl
pcl                      1.13.1           Point Cloud Library (PCL) is open source library for 2D/3D image and point...
pcl[apps]                                 Build application examples/samples that show how PCL works
pcl[cuda]                                 CUDA support for PCL
pcl[examples]                             Build PCL examples
pcl[libusb]                               Build USB RGBD-Camera drivers
pcl[opengl]                               OpenGL support for PCL
pcl[openni2]                              OpenNI2 support for PCL
pcl[pcap]                                 PCAP support for PCL
pcl[qt]                                   Qt support for PCL
pcl[simulation]                           Build Point Cloud Library Simulation
pcl[surface-on-nurbs]                     Fitting NURBS to point clouds
pcl[tools]                                Build PCL utilities
pcl[visualization]                        Build visualization
pcl[vtk]                                  An alias for visualization
```

How should I modify `vcpkg.json` so that the modules of each packages are installed for my own purpose?

---

### Edit 24.01.18

Solved the problem, but other problem occured.
Firstly, the following `vcpkg.json` manifest file successfully installed the packages with specific modules. The `vtk` which is dependency of `pcl[visualization]` is installed automatically, so I removed the `vtk` from the dependencies.

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": [
    {
      "name": "opencv4",
      "features": [ "default-features", "png" ]

    },
    {
      "name": "pcl",
      "features": [ "visualization" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I compile the project, all headers of `pcl/visualization` couldn't find the `vtk` headers. So I added header path of `vtk` manually, and solved the problem.

```
<AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
  $(SolutionDir)vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\include\vtk-9.2;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
```

Still don't know why.